# SQL Server/TSQL - Get column literal data type (with length)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to accomplish a table like the default design's table (right click table and press design):

[image: Data Type With length]

With the following query I can get the length assigned for each field in my table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tablename
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

However imagine a data type like `text` where CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is not null (2147483647 instead) but it's value should be only 'text' in the data type column.

Any ideas how can I get this behavior correct? Every other question doesn't want the "literal" data type.

Edit: Some people couldn't understand what I pretend, I will try to explain better. I want the full data type from a column, I even gave the expected output (data type column). Imagine I have a table with some columns like int
, text, varchar, datetime2. I want the data type like this: `int`, `varchar(120)`, `text`, `datetime2(7)`. This result is the data type column from the design column.

Comment: Show me the query result please

Comment: Can you rephrase the question or post the current result and expected result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is an example T-SQL script that will return the full column definition. You can remove the properties you don't need if you don't want the complete column definition.

```
DECLARE @SourceTableName nvarchar(261) = N'Person.Address';
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN c.is_computed = 1 
            THEN QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' AS (' + cc.definition + N')'
        ELSE
            QUOTENAME(c.name) 
            + N' ' + TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id)
            + CASE 
                --types without length, precision, or scale specification
                WHEN TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id) IN (N'int',N'bigint',N'smallint',N'tinyint',N'money',N'smallmoney',N'real',N'datetime',N'smalldatetime',N'bit',N'image',N'text',N'uniqueidentifier',N'date',N'ntext',N'sql_variant',N'hierarchyid','geography',N'timestamp',N'xml') 
                    THEN N''
                --types with precision and scale specification
                WHEN TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id) in (N'decimal',N'numeric') 
                    THEN N'(' + CAST(c.precision AS nvarchar(5)) + N',' + CAST(c.scale AS nvarchar(5)) + N')'
                --types with scale specification only
                WHEN TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id) in (N'time',N'datetime2',N'datetimeoffset') 
                    THEN N'(' + CAST(c.scale AS nvarchar(5)) + N')'
                --float default precision is 53 - add precision when column has a different precision value
                WHEN TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id) in (N'float')
                    THEN CASE WHEN c.precision = 53 THEN N'' ELSE N'(' + CAST(c.precision AS nvarchar(5)) + N')' END
                --types with max length specification
                ELSE N'(' + CASE c.max_length WHEN -1 THEN N'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS nvarchar(20)) END + N')'
        END
        + CASE WHEN c.is_filestream = 1 THEN N' FILESTREAM' ELSE N'' END
        + COALESCE(N' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name, N'')
        + CASE WHEN c.is_sparse = 1 THEN N' SPARSE' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN c.is_identity = 1 THEN N' IDENTITY(' + CAST(IDENT_SEED(@SourceTableName) AS nvarchar(20)) + N',' + CAST(IDENT_INCR(@SourceTableName) AS nvarchar(20)) + N')' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN c.is_rowguidcol = 1 THEN N' ROWGUIDCOL' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN N' NULL' ELSE N' NOT NULL' END
    END
FROM sys.columns AS c (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns AS cc (NOLOCK) ON
    cc.object_id = c.object_id
    AND cc.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@SourceTableName)
ORDER BY c.column_id;
```

Results, from the AdventureWorks database Person.Address table:

```
[AddressID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
[AddressLine1] nvarchar(120) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
[AddressLine2] nvarchar(120) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
[City] nvarchar(60) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
[StateProvinceID] int NOT NULL
[PostalCode] nvarchar(30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
[SpatialLocation] geography NULL
[rowguid] uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL
[ModifiedDate] datetime NOT NULL
```

Comment: That's exactly what I pretended to, just had to convert to information schema (need to be multi platform based).

Comment: @Exprove, the only reason I didn't use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views is because they don't expose all the needed column properties for SQL Server and the same is true for other DBMS products. But if you only need name, type, and nullability, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are fine and will work with ANSI compliant DBMS products.

Comment: @Dan Guzman, is there any way to determine (for any type) whether it requires a length to it's definition, or requires precision/scale? I've been looking for a flag on sys.types for something like "requires_length" and "requires_precscale". Above you're using a case statement. I cannot find anything like this. Any ideas?

Comment: @MarkRoworth, unfortunately, I don't believe the catalog views expose meta-data to facilitate the precision/scale specification when required. That's why I used a `CASE` expression with hard-coded data type names. A more robust way to reverse engineer DDL is with SMO APIs, such as with [`Scripter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/scripting) object methods.

Comment: @Dan, thanks v much. Thought perhaps I was missing something. SMO has a fair learning curve to it, so I'll probably just create a types table that extends sys.types for my own purposes with this info in, and join to that. Thanks for your help.